# Enable Samsung Pass after manual password entry

Tags: android, passwords, samsung-mobile, fingerprint

We use the android Blackberry Work app for work mail on mobile (yes... thank you for keeping laughter to a minimum). When configuring the app with our corp mail environment I have to enter the domain, mail server, etc and our corp login credentials, then make the app password. So Samsung Pass pops up on the corp password first and I have to cancel because I want Samsung Pass to remember the app's password, not my corp password.(now Samsung Pass is OFF for this app). Then I finally enter the app password I'm good to go.

But isn't there a way to go back in some settings somewhere and flip on Samsung Pass for the app so it will ask me to remember again?

Settings-> Lock Screen and Security-> Samsung Pass-> Settings... there's nothing here to turn on.

Settings-> Apps-> Work-> ... there's nothing here to turn on.

Settings-> Apps-> Autofill with Samsung Pass... there's nothing here to turn on.

I suppose the question applies to any installed app. How do I make Samsung Pass ask me again to remember a password? Or do I have to drop an app and reinstall it for that first password entry?

Thanks